# Batch file won't copy folder and files from batch directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, robocopy, system-variable

I have a batch file with three multiple choice options. If I select `A`, it is supposed to copy a folder called `Files` (located in the same root directory as the batch file) to the root of the `C:\` drive. I can't seem to understand why the `%SystemDrive%` variable isn't working and wants to point to `C:\Windows\system32`.

Any ideas?

**run.bat**

```
@echo off
set /a _Debug=0
::==========================================
:: Get Administrator Rights
set _Args=%*
if "%~1" NEQ "" (
  set _Args=%_Args:"=%
)
fltmc 1>nul 2>nul || (
  cd /d "%~dp0"
  cmd /u /c echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~dp0"" && ""%~dpnx0"" ""%_Args%""", "", "runas", 1 > "%temp%\GetAdmin.vbs"
  "%temp%\GetAdmin.vbs"
  del /f /q "%temp%\GetAdmin.vbs" 1>nul 2>nul
  exit
)

@ECHO OFF
TITLE WINDOWS AUTOMATION UTILITY
COLOR 02
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO THIS UTILITY HELPS AUTOMATE WINDOWS 10
ECHO ======================================
ECHO.
:MENU
ECHO  [A]   Copy 'Files' directory from installation media to System Drive
ECHO  [B]   Set default Start menu for all users
ECHO  [C]   EXIT Remove bloatware apps from Windows 10

choice /C ABC /M "Select Mode:" /N
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 goto End
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto B
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto A

::
:B
CLS
ECHO THIS IS B
TIMEOUT 2 >nul
CLS
GOTO MENU

::
:A
CLS
ECHO THIS IS A
TIMEOUT 2 >nul
CLS
ROBOCOPY "%~dp0Files" %SystemDrive% /MT
GOTO MENU

::
:End
CLS
ECHO You've reached the end
PAUSE
EXIT 0
```

**Robocopy result**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 23 March 2020 00:15:09
   Source : D:\Users\Will\Documents\IT Projects\Windows\Windows 10 Image\Files\
     Dest : C:\Windows\system32\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MT:8 /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**

@Durry42 
Typing `Set` into Command Prompt does return `C:\`

@aschipfl
I think I tried appending a backslash at the end of `%SystemDrive%` and it made no difference.

Comment: `%SystemDrive%` just contains a drive specification (usually `C:`); this constitutes a relative path unless you append `\ `to get something like `C:\ `as the destination; otherwise the current directory of `C:` is used, which depends on where and how you started the script. *N. B.:* that's not multiple but *single* choice...

Comment: In a cmd window, run `set` and see what the current value is for the `%SystemDrive%` variable